# Dependency issue with spark-sql-kafka with spark-submit

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I have written a simple driver class in scala that uses **spark-sql-kafka** for structured streaming. I have used eclipse+maven to package it into a jar. Relevant part of `pom.xml` file is as follows:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-csv_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The, I submit the resulting jar file to `spark-submit` using following command:

```
spark-submit --properties-file {path}/kafka-streaming-conf --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.0.2 --class TestStreamDriver --master yarn {path}/StructuredStreaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

`kafka-streaming-conf` is as follows:

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions    -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyName -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyName -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080

spark.jars.ivySettings {path}/ivysettings_proxy.xml
```

`ivysettings_proxy.xml` file is as follows:

```
<ivysettings>
   <settings defaultResolver="default" /> 
   <credentials host = "proxyName:8080" username = "" passwd = ""/>
   <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-public.xml" /> 
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-shared.xml" /> 
   <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-local.xml" /> 
   <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-main-chain.xml" /> 
   <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings-default-chain.xml"/> 
  </ivysettings>
```

I also changed `JAVA_OPTS` variable by:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyName -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyName -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080"
```

When I run spark-submit with above command, it tries to download from maven repository and other urls and then exists with `Connection timed out` error.

How can I make spark-submit download dependencies through a proxy?

Thanks.

Comment: Check proxy connections and repositories configured but for time being you can download that jar manually and provide it spark-submit with --jar option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Adding jars or making a fat jar did not work for me. I was able to work out a solution, which I summarised below.

Comment: Solution you mentioned is repo connection configuration related which I suspected and asked to check. Adding jars options will definitely work unless you specified --packages option along with --jar option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is:

I changed spark-submit properties file to:

```
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions  -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyName -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyName -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions    -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyName -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyName -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
```

which led to a certificate error.

Then I added certificate for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/

to `{path}/jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\security\cacerts` file. (I used a free program called portecle to add certificates to cacerts file. )

Since I run spark-submit in yarn mode, I had to copy new cacerts file to all nodes with:

```
pscp.pssh -h cluster-hosts ./cacerts  {path}/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/lib/security/
```